# Trying to have a Null Check inside a SpELValueProvider for SOLR Indexing in SAP Commerce

Tags: spring, solr, sap-commerce-cloud

The code that was being set as a parameter for the SpELValueProvider is this:

```
getProduct() instanceof T(de.hybris.platform.b2ctelcoservices.model.TmaSimpleProductOfferingModel) ? getProduct().getManufacturerAID() : getAffectedProductOffering().getManufacturerAID()
```

But this does not have a Null Check and when a product has the attribute as null I get this:

> ERROR [solr indexer thread] [DefaultIndexerWorker] [Indexer worker 4 (UPDATE index operation on Index/PriceRow)] failed to process index items due to Failed to index item with PK 8796597610783: Failed to resolve values for item with PK: 8796597610783, by resolver: springELValueProvider, for property: manufacturerAID, reason: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method getManufacturerAID() on null context object

I have tried using a "double" ternary expression like this:

```
getProduct() =! null ? (getProduct() instanceof T(de.hybris.platform.b2ctelcoservices.model.TmaSimpleProductOfferingModel) ? getProduct().getManufacturerAID() : getAffectedProductOffering().getManufacturerAID()) : ""
```

But looks like SpEL doesnt accept a ternary expression inside another..

> ERROR [solr indexer thread] [DefaultIndexerWorker] [Indexer worker 2 (UPDATE index operation on Index/PriceRow)] failed to process index items due to Failed to index item with PK 8796097610783: Failed to resolve values for item with PK: 8796597610783, by resolver: springELValueProvider, for property: manufacturerAID, reason: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'qmark(?)'
> de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.exceptions.IndexerException: Failed to index item with PK 8796597610783: Failed to resolve values for item with PK: 8796597610783, by resolver: springELValueProvider, for property: manufacturerAID, reason: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'qmark(?)'

Comment: does making it 2 conditions works? `getProduct() != null && getProduct() instanceof T(de.hybris.platform.b2ctelcoservices.model.TmaSimpleProductOfferingModel) ? getProduct().getManufacturerAID() : getAffectedProductOffering().getManufacturerAID()`